# How do I use Robocopy to exclude ALL subfolders under a chosen folder?

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to use Robocopy in a way that excludes all subfolders under a chosen folder.  In other words, I only want to target a folder and robocopy only the files within it but not it's subfolders.  Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 9):

Excluding subfolders is actually the default behavior of robocopy, or at least the version that comes with Windows 7.  (In order to copy the sub-directories you would have to add the `/S` or `/E` option to the command.)

So, you can just use `robocopy source-folder target-folder`.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I actually tested this before I posted. It does work like that. (The version of robocopy that comes with W7.)

Comment: @HopelessN00b He's right. no-recursion is the default behavior at least for versions 6.1 (shipping with Windows 7) and XP010 (from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit). See [here](http://www.planetcobalt.net/robocopy.shtml) for the transcript of a test.

Comment: There are some big differences in robocopy versions between XP and Win7 and some subtle ones from version to version. Whenever I use robocopy in a script I make absolutely sure to call a specific version of the command. Never can tell which version would be called when going through %PATH%.

Answer (score 5):

I've never done this, so this will be kind of a guess:

```
/lev:0
```

Copies only the top N levels of the source directory tree.

```
/xd *
```

Excludes directories that match the specified names and paths.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 3):

[From the `robocopy` reference page at ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) (which you may wish to bookmark, I have):

1. `>/LEV:n : Only copy the top n LEVels of the source tree.` (`LEV:0` is what you're looking for, it will copy 0 folders down in the tree from the directory where you target it, so only the files in the folder you target.)
2. `/XD dirs [dirs]... : eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.`

   - also an exclude files switch, `/XF file [file]... : eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.` if that's really what you're after.